# SwiftUI why doesn't my view update once this object property changes?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
@ObservedObject var vm: PlayerViewModel
var body : some View {
  Button("Test"){
        Task{         
           await vm.getPlayer(username: username)
           switch vm.state{
           case .success(var player):
               let docRef = vm.db.collection("players").document(player.displayname)
               docRef.getDocument {document, error in
               if let document = document, document.exists {
                    print("document exists")
                    player.todayFinalKills = document["todayFinalKills"] as? Int
                    print(player.todayFinalKills ?? 0)
               }
         }
   }
}
```

So I just have some firestore database here(not really relevant to the question I don't think) I'm calling some function, I check the state of some enum and then check if the document exists, if it exists I change one property in the associated data of the enum. This is what this prints:

[image: Picture]

So it does seem that the property is getting updated in the player object for sure but then I have another view with a List

```
struct DailyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: PlayerViewModel
    var body: some View {
        List{
              Text("\(player.todayFinalKills ?? 0)") 
        }
    }
}
```

But this view always has a zero, implying that this still thinks todayFinalKills is nil? If it literally prints it out as 8291 why is this happening? I was thinking maybe if I switch on a enum like this and extract the associated data maybe it creates a copy but I wasn't able to find much information about this online. Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening? I am passing the same ViewModel into all these views.

Edit: PlayerViewModel.swift

```
import FirebaseFirestore
import Foundation
@MainActor
class PlayerViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    enum PlayerState {
        case na
        case loading
        case success(data: Player)
        case failed(error : Error)
        
        
    }
    
   
    var db = Firestore.firestore()
    @Published private(set) var state: PlayerState = .na
    
    
    private let service: PlayerService
    
    init(service: PlayerService)
    {
        self.service = service
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
  
    
    
    
    func getPlayer(username: String) async {
        state = .loading
        
        do{
            let uuid = try await service.fetchUUID(username: username)
            let player = try await service.fetchPlayer(uuid: uuid)
            
            state = .success(data: player)
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
            state = .failed(error: error)
        }
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

DailyView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct DailyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: PlayerViewModel
    var body: some View {
        switch vm.state{
        case .success(let player):
            List{
                
                
                Text("\(player.todayFinalKills ?? 0)")
                
                
                
                
                
            }
            
            
        default:
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}

struct DailyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DailyView(vm: PlayerViewModel(service: PlayerService()))
    }
}
```

LoginView.swift

```
struct LoginView: View {
    
    
    
    @ObservedObject var vm : PlayerViewModel
    @State private var username = ""
    @State private var profileLoaded = false
    private var searchAllowed : Bool{
        if(username.count>2)
        {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                
                VStack{
                    
                  
                    Button{
                        Task{
                            
                            
                            await vm.getPlayer(username: username)
                            switch vm.state{
                            case .success(var player):
                                let docRef = vm.db.collection("players").document(player.displayname)
                                docRef.getDocument {document, error in
                                    if let document = document, document.exists {
                                       
                                        player.todayFinalKills = document["todayFinalKills"] as? Int
                                        print(player.todayFinalKills ?? 0)
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        let stats : [String : Int] = [
                                            
                                            "todayFinalKills": player.stats.Bedwars?.final_kills_bedwars ?? 0,
                                            "todayFinalDeaths" : player.stats.Bedwars?.final_deaths_bedwars ?? 0,
                                            "todayBedwarsWins" : player.stats.Bedwars?.wins_bedwars ?? 0,
                                            "todayBedwarsLosses" : player.stats.Bedwars?.losses_bedwars ?? 0,
                                            "todayTntRunLosses" : player.stats.TNTGames?.deaths_tntrun ?? 0,
                                            "todayTntRunWins" : player.achievements.tntgames_tnt_run_wins ?? 0,
                                            
                                        
                                               ]
                                        vm.db.newPlayerDocument(data: stats, username: player.displayname, uuid: player.uuid)
                                    }
                                }
                                profileLoaded = true
                            default:
                                print("default")
                            }
                            
                            
                        
                        }
                    } label:
                    {
                        
                        ZStack{
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                .fill(.gray)
                                .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                                
                            Text("Search")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                            
                                
                                
                    }
                    }
```

Model.swift

```
struct Player : Codable, Hashable, Equatable{
    static func == (lhs: Player, rhs: Player) -> Bool {
        lhs.uuid == rhs.uuid
    }
    
    // so a player contains many objects, like stats, achievements, etc
    var stats: Stats
    var achievements: Achievements
    var displayname: String
    var uuid : String
    var networkExp: Int
    var knownAliases : [String]
    var karma: Int
    var newPackageRank : String? //this could be MVP_PLUS
    var rankPlusColor : String? //this could be LIGHT_PURPLE
    
    //daily statistics for the player.
    
    **var todayFinalKills : Int?**
    var todayBedwarsLosses : Int?
    var todayBedwarsWins: Int?
    var todayFinalDeaths: Int?
    var todayTntRunWins: Int?
    var TodayTntRunLosses: Int?
    
    //
```

Comment: 1. Show us how you declared the vm in the first place. 2. Show us the inside of your vm class.

Comment: How do ensure that both view are using the same player view model instance?

Comment: @tail I tried to include everything you asked for sorry it was a little messy but that's the code and Paul I have one main view everything starts off with view a StateObject var vm : PlayerViewModel = PlayerViewModel() and every view I created has a ObservedObject var vm : PlayerViewModel, I pass in the original vm into every single view I create.

Comment: Now I'm thinking there is one thing I realized @tail could this possibly be a problem? What if the state enum turns into the .success case which causes some view to update, but then I change the associated data for that enum, so it's still in .success case but the associated data changed will that still cause the View to change or does it not see that happening?

Comment: @DanBriggs I see you use “player.todayFinalKill” to print, but I don’t see this one being declared anywhere in your code.

Comment: @tail I have this line ``print(player.todayFinalKills ?? 0)`` in ``LoginView.swift`` then in ``DailyView.swift`` I have a line ``Text("\(player.todayFinalKills ?? 0)")``. The print prints a number like I showed in the image but this Text View never updates and just stays nil(and becomes 0 of course because of the nil coalescing operator)

Comment: @DanBriggs that's what I am trying to tell you. I don't see any "player.todayKill" variable in your code or your vm or your struct. How did you display anything with this? It's not even related to your vm or viewmodel class.

Comment: Oh yeah that's my fault I forgot to include the Model.swift file as you can see that's a property of the Player struct I created, the ViewModel has an instance of that class as associated data.

Comment: I don't know whether you have seen these, but please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The big issue with answering your question is that you haven't posted an MRE. You are most likely getting 0 because `player.todayFinalKills` is `nil`.